# What is it called when you have a single-pole recursive digital lowpass filter where the coefficients don't add up to unity?

Tags: digital-filters

Is there a name for a single-pole recursive digital lowpass filter where the coefficients don't quite add up to 1?

For example: with the filter `y[n]=a0*x[n]+b1*y[n-1]` instead of using coefficients

```
a0=0.1
b1=0.9
```

What if I used

```
a0=0.11
b1=0.9
```

Is there a name for this, or is it just functionally equivalent to something else like `y[n]=a0*x[n]+b1*y[n-1]+c0`

Also, at what point will the filter become unstable? The example above where the coefficients add up to 1.01 looks stable to me but I think a0=0.009 and b1=1.001 would be unstable. Where's the line where it crosses from stable to unstable? b1=1?

Answer (score 1):

Stability only depends on $b_1$, and it needs to satisfy $|b_1|<1$ for stability of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik It's not called anything other than a *first order recursive filter*, aka single pole IIR...

And it's not functionally equivalent to the last line you have written. There's no constant term...